# Make a circular border around text

Tags: html, css

Right now I would like to have a plus sign with a circle around it.

http://jsfiddle.net/dtracers/cvtztcy1/1/

```
<h1>TEXY TXT <span>+</span></h1>

<style>
span {
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width: 1px 3px 1px 1px;
    padding:0px;
    padding-bottom:0.125em;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin:0px;
}

/* Just to see if that would modify anything */
h1 {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
</style>
```

After looking at it you can tell that this is not a circle but instead an elipse.
I have realize that it is the text height that is causing this issue but is there a way to make it appear closer.

The background is dynamic so I can not use an image.
And I would rather not have a floating element that depended on absolute positioning.

I would also like the circle in height to be equal to its current width.
I know I can just make it wider but I don't want a giant circle I want a tight small circle

**EDIT**
For those that are saying this is the same question it is kinda.
The difference between what I am asking and what that person is asking is that in their case the circle is larger than the bounds of the text.

What I am asking is for a circle that is smaller than the bounds of the text.
As such none of the solutions given there will apply to my question.

Comment: Is this work for you ? http://jsbin.com/faxubibazitu/1/edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using `:after` pseudo element. check the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/faxubibazitu/1/edit)**.

```
span {
  position:relative;
  padding:0; margin:0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
span:after
{
content:"";
position:absolute;
display:inline-block;
left:-1px;
top:7px;
background:gold;
border-radius: 50%;
width:0.5em;
height:0.5em;
font-size:1.3em;
z-index:-1;
}
```

Comment: I basically used a slightly altered version of this.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust your `padding` value in css and all is good :

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cvtztcy1/3/)

```
span {
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width: 1px 3px 1px 1px;
    padding:0 2%; /* updated */
    /* padding-bottom:0.125em;  removed */
    cursor:pointer;
    margin:0px;
}
```

Comment: that just made it wider.
I am actually looking for it to be less tall and closer to the plus sign

Comment: then reduce your padding more

Answer (score 0):

This will lead to a perfect circle:

```
span {
    border-radius: 150px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    padding:1% 2%;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin:0px;
    width:200px;
    line-height:300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to make the span have equal `width` and `height` using `em` so it naturally adjusts to the font size.

```
h1 span {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 0.9em;
   height: 0.9em;
   line-height: 0.8em;
   text-align: center;
   color: teal;
   background-color: palegoldenrod;
   border: 0.18em solid;
   border-radius: 1000px;
   padding-left: 1px;
   cursor: pointer;
   }
```

Then center the plus sign with `line-height` and `text-align`.

[image: circled-plus-sign]

Fiddle with the CSS:
http://jsfiddle.net/zx2c4drL

Comment: one suggestion  you should use border-radius value in `%` not in `px`.